# MX Notify Control not parsing Channel Entries tag

Tags: mx-notify

I'm trying to replicate the example [here](http://www.eec.ms/user_guide/mx-notify-control/example.html#394) but Channel Entries tag in the notification email is not rendering at all. I've tried both Plain Text and HTML emails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the entry showing when you open the page in your browser? (Use the entry_id to debug.)

Two things come to my mind:

1. Is the status of the entry other than 'open'? Than you should use the parameter status="[the other status]"
2. Is the entry_date a date in the future? Than use the parameter show_future_entries="yes"

Comment: Ah yes - I'm sure it's the status. It is something other than 'open'. Hadn't thought of that.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, no still nothing.

I can see it in my browser if I replace {entry_id} with the actual ID number, but not if I use entry_id="{entry_id}".

{mbr_screen_name} is also not rendering.

Comment: Have you tried adding `dynamic="no"`?

Comment: I just heard from my client and it seems the Channel Entries tag is now rendering, even though it does not when I view that template in the browser. And the {mbr_screen_name} still is not rendering.